# Modelo ApplicationUser no sale en la lista ModelClass

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core, .net-core

Cuando intento agregar un *scafolding* con *Entity Framework* la clase que esta en `.Models` no aparece, se llama `ApplicationUser` y no esta en la lista, ¿cómo la cargo?

***Listado:***
[image: Listado]

Comment: me dijeron que ejecute este comando `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name UsuariosController -m ApplicationUser -dc ApplicationDbContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries` desde el powershell pero no paso nada, me devolvio un method not found...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes ir a la carpeta donde esta el proyecto y ahi abres el powershell

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para que puedas ejecutar el siguiente codigo.

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name UsuariosController -m ApplicationUser -dc ApplicationDbContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries
```

Nota: El proyecto debe de estar cerrado en el Visual Studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ya obtendrás el controlador Usuario y sus vistas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La razón 3 razones más comunes para que un modelo no salga listado

1. no has compilado tu solución luego de haber creado el modelo
2. no has puesto el modelo en la carpeta indicada, el scafolding esta orientado por convenciones
3. el modelo, la clase no está marcada como pública